# submit checkbox in firestore using flask

Tags: html, flask, google-cloud-firestore, checkbox

how to submit checkbox value true or false when checked and unchecked the box. i am getting true value but when i submit the checkbox unchecked the form field crashes.

````
elif request.method == "POST":
active_client = bool(request.form["activeClient"])


client{
"activeClient": active_client,
}

```
try:
            db.collection('clients').document(client_id).set(client)
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Well my bad i just needed to add getlist and change the parenthesis.

```
active_client = bool(request.form.getlist("activeClient"))
```

it solved the problem.